# laravel selected value after get collection and modified

Tags: php, json, laravel, subset, array-intersect

I have product model linked with discount and category;

```
$products = Product::with('discounts')->with('categories')->get();
```

I then manipulate products based on category

```
foreach ($products as $item) {
    if (category_condition) {
        $item['new_prod_attribute'] = 'data_cat';
    }

    if (discount_condition) {
        $item['new_prod_attribute1'] = 'data_disc';
    }
}
```

Now I want to get some selective data like: `product->id,name,new_prod_attribute,new_prod_attribute1; category->name; discount->offer_name as subset_data`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

```
$productData = $products->map(function ($product) {
    $data = [
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->name,
        ...
        'category_name' => $product->categories->name,
    ];
    
    if (category_condition) {
        $data['new_prod_attribute'] = 'data_cat';
    }

    if (discount_condition) {
        $data['new_prod_attribute1'] = 'data_disc';
    }

    return $data;
});
```

When you dump `$productData` you've all the data

Comment: looks like map manually. Is there any way to `$subset_to_get = ['id','name','category_name','new_prod_attribute','new_prod_attribute1','discount']` and intersect it with `productData` ?